# Passing form variables to action creator in React-Redux

Tags: redux

In a React-Redux app, I'm trying to pass the form variable from a component to the action creator without using Redux-Form, Formic or any other extension.

**myForm.js**

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchData } from "../actions/myActions";

class myForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      from: "",
      to: ""
    };
    this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
  }

onFormSubmit(event) {
event.preventDefault();

const from = event.target.elements.from.value;
const to = event.target.elements.to.value;

this.setState({
      from: from,
      to: to
    });

    this.props.fetchData(
      this.state.from,
      this.state.to,
    );
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
            <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="from"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="to"
            />
          </div>
    </form>
 </div>


    export default connect(
      null,
      { fetchData }
    )(myForm);
```

I'm passing the action creator **fetchData** to myForm component and on form submit invoke the onFormSubmit function, which passes the form variables to fetchData like this:

```
this.props.fetchData(
   this.state.from,
   this.state.to,
);
```

Then inside myActions.js I try to access those form variables and start an API request.

**myActions.js**

```
import { FETCH_DATA } from "./types";
import axios from "axios";
const APP_KEY = <my api key>;

export const fetchData = (from,to) => async dispatch => {
  const response = await axios.get`${URL}/${from}/to/${to}?app_key=${APP_KEY}`;

  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_DATA,
    payload: response.data.journeys
  });
};
```

Is what I'm trying the right approach?
Unfortunately it seems that variables **from** and **to** don't get passed to the action creator inside myAction.js.

Answer (score 1):

`setState` is an async operation, hence `this.props.fetchData` is called, before the state is even set. You need to use the callback in the second argument of `setState`in ***myForm.js*** which is excuted after the state has been updated.

```
this.setState({
    from: from,
    to: to
}, () => {
    this.props.fetchData(this.state.from,this.state.to)
});
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding !